# Return the average mark for all student in that Section

Tags: python, whitespace, space, average

I know it was asked already but the answers the super unclear

The first requirement is to open a file (sadly I have no idea how to do that)
The second requirement is a section of code that does the following:

Each line represents a single student and consists of a student number, a name, a section code and a midterm grade, all separated by **whitespace**

So I don't think i can target that element due to it being separate by whitespace?

Here is an excerpt of the file, showing line structure

```
987654322  Xu  Carolyn  L0101   19.5
233432555    Jones  Billy Andrew      L5101   16.0
555432345    Patel  Amrit                 L0101   13.5
888332441    Fletcher Bobby L0201   18
777998713   Van Ryan  Sarah Jane         L5101   20 
877633234    Zhang  Peter             L0102   9.5
543444555    Martin  Joseph           L0101   15    
876543222    Abdolhosseini  Mohammad Mazen  L0102 18.5
```

I was provided the following hints:

- Notice that the number of names per student varies.
- Use `rstrip()` to get rid of extraneous whitespace at the end of the lines.

I don't understand the second hint.

This is what I have so far:

```
counter = 0  
elements = -1  

for sets in the_file  
    elements = elements + 1  
    if elements = 3
```

I know it has something to do with `readlines()` and the targeting the section code.

Comment: What is the question you want to ask?

Comment: http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~csc108h/fall/exercises/e3/grade_file.txt

Comment: Using the readlines in this case. And am I sure that I cant continue with the way I wrote already.

Comment: Did you try to Google `python rstrip` to better understand the 2nd hint?

Comment: Did you try to Google `how to open a file in python`?

Comment: This is homework, so we can't help too much. Here is a hint:  `Yes you can (probably _need_ to) use white space` to identify the elements within a line, the trick will be to do so `from the end of the line` (notice how there is no ambiguity, the mark and the section Id are always the last two tokens on the line, and the Student ID the very first: The name is whatever is left, and we don't really care how many individual words it is made of.

Answer (score 1):

```
marks = [float(line.strip().split()[-1]) for line in open('path/to/input/file')]
average = sum(marks)/len(marks)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

[Open and writing to files](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)
[strip method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip)

Something like this?

```
data = {}
with open(filename) as f:#open a file

    for line in f.readlines():#proceed through file lines

        #next row is to split data using spaces and them skip empty using strip
        stData = [x.strip() for x in line.split() if x.strip()]

        #assign to variables
        studentN, studentName, sectionCode, midtermGrade = stData
        if sectionCode not in data:
            data[sectionCode] = []

        #building dict, key is a section code, value is a tuple with student info
        data[sectionCode].append([studentN, studentName, float(midtermGrade)]

#make calculations
for k,v in data.iteritems():#iteritems returns you (key, value) pair on each iteration
    print 'Section:' + k + ' Grade:' + str(sum(x[2] for x in v['grade']))
```

Comment: I don't think we're helping students with their homework and generally with their studies by providing ready to go code.

Comment: would you suggest to remove my answer?

Comment: I think it is help. For computer science sometimes i think its easier to understand after seeing the finished product. remove if u will

Comment: [`setdefault()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) or [`DefaultDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) will get rid of your inner `if` check.

Comment: sure i know but it looks like the level is really beginer

Comment: @ArtsiomRudzenka: my point, exactly.  It appears we're enabling the OP, who's, BTW, likely to keep his handle `ALWAYSneedHelp`.  The idea that "it's easier to understand after seeing the solution" is preposterous.  While there is much learning to be done by observing other people's code, such review should only take place _after_ one has done an `earnest` effort at resolving the problem at hand by oneself.  Apparently little attention was paid to the class and to the course material: the OP has no idea about opening a file, nor did he think of googling this simple issue.

Answer (score 0):

more or less:

```
infile = open('grade_file.txt', 'r')
score = 0
n = 0
for line in infile.readlines():
    score += float(line.rstrip().split()[-1])
    n += 1

avg = score / n
```

Comment: think you forgot to convert string to float - otherwise you merging strings representations into one big string